Union information from two tables in Azure Resource Graph
I am trying to get patching information about virtual machines whitin Azure and to filter them by tag using Resource Graph. The end goal is to filer the machines by tag "Environment" with value "Prod" and to list all missing updates for the machines by their names and classification.
I have tried with the below query but "join" is joing only the informarion that is matching from both tables and the unmatched are popullated with "null". Is there any way that I can combine matching and unmatching records from two different tables?
resources 
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend environmentTag = tags.Environment
| where environmentTag == "Prod"
| join kind = fullouter (
    patchassessmentresources
    | where type has "softwarepatches"
    | extend prop = parse_json(properties)
    | extend PatchName = properties.patchName
    | extend UpdateType = properties.classifications
    | where UpdateType contains "Security" or UpdateType contains "Critical" or UpdateType contains "Other"
    | extend machineName = tostring(split(id, '/', 8)) 
    ) on $left.name == $right.machineName
| project machineName, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, PatchName, UpdateType


To combine matching and non-matching records from two different tables, you can use the union operator in Azure Resource Graph queries instead of join. The union operator allows you to combine rows from multiple tables.
